# Convert ISO Date to UTC Time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, salesforce

I have an ISO Date string and using Javascript, I'd like to extract the time from it.

How can I turn `2016-07-02T19:27:28.000+0000` into `7:27 pm`?  I have tried `Date.Parse` with little success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it´s the best date library I have worked with.

Comment: perfect:  moment(Date.parse(result[i].Activity_Time_Stamp__c)).format("h:mm A")

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at [toTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString) and [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString). You can use them like below.

```
var d = new Date("2016-07-02T19:27:28.000+0000");
console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString());
console.log(d.toTimeString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use moment.js or any dependency what so ever, why use a dependency?

Simple:

```
new Date(new Date().toUTCString()).toISOString().split("T")[1].split(".")[0];
```

Comment: (!) .toUTCString() removes milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the date in UTC format

```
var utcDate = new Date("2016-07-02T19:27:28.000+0000").toUTCString();
```

Get the time from utcDate.

```
var time = utcDate.split(' ')[4];
```

Conver the 24 hr time format to 12 hr format using getDesireTime function.

```
function getDesireTime(time) {
     hr = parseInt(time.split(':')[0]);
     amOrpm = hr < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Set AM/PM
     hr = hr % 12 || '00'; // Adjust hours
     return`${hr}:${time.split(':')[1]} ${amOrpm}`
 }
console.log(getDesireTime(time));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with moment js

```
moment('2016-07-02T19:27:28.000+0000').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```